# Pywinauto has gone nuts

Tags: python, pywinauto

Below is the image of code and error:

[Code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMNpa.png)

Below are the images of similar problem but using different line of code:

[Code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OpXA.png)

[Code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pS8n.png)

[Code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpX5F.png)

[Code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUq6w.png)

I have uploaded the images of the code_snippet. Sometimes `Code1` works in the following line `dlg.print_control_identifiers()`

and many times it doesn't when I rerun the code.

I have uploaded 4 different images of `Code2` in different scenario and error. I am frustrated very deeply. Can anybody guide me?

Possible errors

```
ElementAmbiguousError: There are 2 elements that match the criteria {'title_re': 'Miracle', 'top_level_only': False, 'backend': 'uia', 'process': 23860}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please copy your code hewre, do not put screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disambiguate your search (find only one element), please add more detailed criteria to `child_window()` keywords. Usually we recommend to combine `title` and `control_type` (using `control_type` also improves performance). If you give up finally, try to add `found_index=0` keyword to `child_window()` criteria. It is applied after all other keywords are filtered in.

Comment: Yeah I found a way around the `ElementAmbigousError` but the main reason for me to ask this question here is the error `MatchError: Could not find 'xyz' in 'dict_keys([ ])'`. I am getting name of the windows from `app.windows()` and copy pasting the same string in the `dlg = app[ xyz ]` but I get the MatchError.

Comment: I guess you tried `dlg = app["xyz"]`, right? This attribute or item access is equivalent to `app.window(best_match="xyz")`.

Comment: So are you recommending to use `app.window(best_match="xyz")` instead?

Comment: Not necessary. It's just for better understanding how it works. Of course, classic access by attribute like `app.xyz` looks more compact and nice.

Comment: Well okay, `best_match` seems to be working for me rather than the `app.xyz`. Thanks for making me think that you recommended `best_match` method :-)

Comment: Thanks for reporting different behavior. We will double check it.